# set proxy request timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How is it possible to define proxy connection / read timeout?

I tried doing this (but I get error - undefined method read/open timeout)

```
http = Net::HTTP::Proxy(host, port, user, pass)
http.open_timeout = 5
http.read_timeout = 5
http.start(uri.host) do |http|

end
```

Thanks for help

Comment: This post will solve the problem:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16939969/ruby-increasing-proxy-request-timeout

Answer (score 0):

you are close you need do the follow

```
http = Net::HTTP::Proxy(host, port, user, pass)
http.start(uri.host) do |http|
  http.open_timeout = 5
  http.read_timeout = 5
end
```

you need to move the attributes http like open_timeout inside the block

cheers!