# How to set the timeout for a proxy connection in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http

I know how to [set the open/read timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261725/set-proxy-request-timeout) for the request going through the proxy.  My problem, however, is that occasionally my proxy goes down, and therefore I am unable to ever connect to the proxy.  So I want to be able to set the timeout to connect to the proxy to some value, and then handle the timeout by trying something else.  Any idea how I can set the timeout value for connecting to an http proxy?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First the code, then a bit of explaination below:

```
# get an instance of Net::HTTP that has proxy settings embedded
# see the source:  http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-c-Proxy
proxyclass = Net::HTTP::Proxy("proxy_host");

# Create a new instance of the URL you want to connect to
# NOTE: no connection is attempted yet
proxyinstance = proxyclass.new("google.com");

# Make your setting changes, specifically the timeouts
proxyinstance.open_timeout = 5;
proxyinstance.read_timeout = 5;

# now, attempt connecting through the proxy with the desired
# timeout settings.
proxyinstance.start do |http|
    # do something with the http instance
end
```

The key is realizing `open_timeout` and `read_timeout` are instance variables and that `Net::HTTP::Proxy` actually returns a decorated `Net::HTTP` class.

You would run into this same problem with similar `Net::HTTP` usage.  You must construct it the "long" way, not using the `Net::HTTP.start()` class method shortcut.