# Ruby - increasing proxy request timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, proxy, net-http

I'm trying to access some contents via some proxy servers but I get:

```
<Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Connection timed out - connect(2)>
```

I modified the code and tried to increase the timeout as below:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'net/http'


response = Net::HTTP::Proxy(proxy_ip, proxy_port).get_response(uri.host, uri.path)
response.start(uri.host) do |http|
  http.open_timeout = 5 
  http.read_timeout = 10
end
```

Now it doesn't recagnize the `open_timeout` and `start`

```
undefined method `open_timeout=' for #<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>>
undefined method `start..
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `get_response` on the Proxy(HTTP) class, you get a `Net::HTTPResponse` instance, and it doesn't respond to `start` or `open_timeout=`.

Use `Net::HTTP::Proxy` to create an proxied HTTP class, create an instance of that class, and then modify the timeout settings on that instance. And then you can use the instance to fetch contents from behind a proxy.

```rb
proxy_http = Net::HTTP.Proxy(proxy_ip, proxy_port).new(uri.host)
proxy_http.open_timeout = 5
proxy_http.read_timeout = 10
response = proxy_http.get(uri.path)
```